# C# multi-thread approach in GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a small app. Need your help.

I have a table of 10 columns. Say, i select 5 rows in a list view.
I take all the values of col_1, in a list, pass it to a method.

If all values are equal, set combo_box1 value = "equal" else value = "not equal".

**Current Approach:**

I have 10 lists ( seems pretty lame... isn't it? i had asked a ques regarding this...), one for each col.

10 calls to the method that checks for equality of values, each for one list. Subsequently, set the combo box's(10 combo boxes) values.

If i have say 100 records, i guess the time taken will increase. So, i thought of implementing threads.

**Effort Put:**

I have used the this.Invoke(new Delegate...)  approach for a thread which tries to access a control of Main thread. It works fine. I tried to manipulate this according to my needs. Couldn't do so. Please help me out guys.

**[EDIT]**

the main culprit was the image comparison... its taking awfully long time to finish... below is the code...
i'm storing all the image(say col no 3) of say 10 rows in a list...

// other stuffs
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int memcmp(IntPtr b1, IntPtr b2, long count);

// create a list of images
MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(tempImage.Data.Data);
Bitmap artCoverImage = new Bitmap(imageStream);              //  culprit ?
artCoverList.Add(artCoverImage);

// call the method
CheckIfEqual(artCoverList)                                   //  culprit ?

// THE method
private void CheckIfEqual(artCoverList)
{
    Bitmap tempBitMap = artCoverList[0];

`foreach (Bitmap bmp in artCoverList)
{
    if (bmp == null)
        return false;
    if (bmp.Size != tempBitMap.Size)
        return false;

var bd1 = tempBitMap.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), tempBitMap.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    IntPtr bd1scan0 = bd1.Scan0;
    int stride = bd1.Stride;
    long len = stride * tempBitMap.Height;

var bd2 = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    IntPtr bd2scan0 = bd2.Scan0;
    returnValue = memcmp(bd1scan0, bd2scan0, len) == 0;
    bmp.UnlockBits(bd2);
    tempBitMap.UnlockBits(bd1); } }`

I had spent a whole day to get this part image comparison working... i think the part where it converts mem stream to bmp is the culprit...

**[EDIT 2]**

guys...need your help... any idea... how to compare a list of images... other than above...

Thanks,

Dev

Comment: First, depending on what you are doing, increasing the records to 100 should not make that much of a difference, especially if you are only parsing over the list a few times. Second, we need more information here. How did you try to manipulate your thread call? How exactly do you want the thread to work?

Comment: the thing is the number of columns can increase... i would like to call , say 3 threads... each handling 3 cols... like  that..

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a threaded design has its own overhead and adds complexity.  You really only want to consider moving to a threaded model if performance is poor enough to warrant the added complexity.

If you have 100 rows and you are checking equality of 10 columns, then you're doing 1000 equality checks.  Depending on the implementation, this should be a trivial operation with negligible performance ramifications.

Consider profiling your application to see if there is a performance issue.

**EDIT**
Based on your findings (that image comparison is the culprit), you may want to consider using a simple checksum comparison against the respective image byte arrays.

Here is an example of how to do so:
http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2859.htm

Note: MD5 is sufficient in this case and should prove to be slightly faster.

Comment: well.. after profiling i found the bugger who's causing the delay... i have edited the main ques...

Comment: i heard that MD5 comparison is slower than the one i've used... researched a lot before going for this approach... will compare the time taken by both the methods and see... i think it's also taking time during the Bitmap generation from the stream... is there any other way to handle images...?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that instead of using Invoke, check out `BackgroundWorker` .  It has callback events that *automatically* run on the main thread, so it makes updating your UI when you're done easier, so as to avoid cross thread UI exceptions.

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => updateUI();
worker.DoWork += (s, e) => longProcess();

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Since you discovered it's only a single column that causing the delay, multiple threads will not help - you'll still need to wait for the time-consuming thread to finish in the end.  The threading overhead will outweigh the benefits for the other columns.

Comment: i was thinking if i process 99 out of 100 columns in main thread and this time consuming column in another... i would be able to speed up total process...

Answer (score 0):

One way to check if all elements in a list are the same is to stuff them into a `HashSet` and check the amount of items in the `HashSet` afterwards: If you only have one item, then they are all equal...